# Can I Implement Clustered Lighting with WebGL?

Tags: rendering, lighting, webgl

Do current WebGL capabilities allow to use Clustered Lighting? If not what is it missing to allow that? Basically WebGL uses GLES 2, so is that possible with GLES 2?

I want to implement this one:

[Clustered Shading](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~uffe/clustered_shading_preprint.pdf)

And use as fallback this one:

[Alternative to Clustered shading](https://worldoffries.wordpress.com/2015/02/19/simple-alternative-to-clustered-shading-for-thousands-of-lights/)

Comment: Could you [edit] to expand on exactly what you require, and what you have tried? Is there a particular approach to clustered lights that you want to implement? What effect are you looking to achieve?

Comment: WebGL doesn't have compute shaders and I'm not sure if clustered lighting would be fast enough without them.